# How can I define a generic function to check if the input is allowed

Tags: python, loops, global

**Permitted Input Checker**
I am attempting to define a generic function which can be called to check if the user input matches a list of valid options.

- valid1 and valid2:   Options
- var:   Name of inputs variable
- text:   The string to be displayed with the input
- var_out:   This should be the variable name of the output containing a valid option

The var_out parameter in the define statement must be changed for different questions but also need to be global to allow the variable to be set then used outside. This results in an error:

name'var_out' is parameter and global

How can i avoid this but still be able to change the name of the output variable?

```
def valid_check(valid1,valid2,var,text,var_out):
    global var_out
    valid = [valid1,valid2]
    var = input(text)
    var = var.lower()
    if var not in valid:
        print ("Try again")
        valid_check(valid1,valid2,var,text,var_out)
    else:
        print("Good")
        var_out = var
        print(var_out)



    valid_check("yes","no",'Play_again',"Do you want to play agian: Yes or no","Question_1")
    print (var_out)
```

***Edit: Realised this would never work. I changed it to this instead***

```
def valid_check(valid1,valid2,var,text):
    valid = [valid1,valid2]
    var = input(text)
    var = var.lower()
    if var not in valid:
        print ("Try again")
        valid_check(valid1,valid2,var,text)
    else:
        print(var+" was accepted")
        return str(var)


Q2 = valid_check("a","b","Q2","a or b:")
print (Q2)
```

But if the answer is valid first time the output works

```
a or b:a
a was accepted
a
```

and if you enter wrong first then enter correct second time the output is 'None'

```
a or b:INVALID
Try again
a or b:a
a was accepted
None
```

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `global` instead of `return`ing a value?

Comment: why are you overwriting the value of `var` with `input`? Why do you even need `var` as an argument to this function?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to record values into a global variable in order to use them later. Instead, it's better to use `return` keyword:

```
def some_method(input):
    return input + 1
```

Then you can assign the result of a method to a variable and use it, like this:

```
a = some_method(5)
// a == 6
```

Furthermore, for the task like yours, it is very unwise to use recursion, as at the very least it will print out `Good` for as many times, as the user has given a wrong input! I suggest using a simple `while` loop as follows:

```
def valid_check(valid1, valid2, text):
    valid = [valid1, valid2]
    var = input(text).lower()
    while var not in valid:
        print("Try again")
        var = input(text).lower()
    print("Good")
    return var


var_out = valid_check("yes", "no", "Do you want to play agian: Yes or no")
print(var_out)
```

Notice, that you do not need to pass a variable to store the result into as a parameter, as well as for recording intermediate results. Hope this helps!

**Edit for OP Edit:**

This why I advised you to use a while loop. In your code, when the input is incorrect, you invoke your function again:

```
def valid_check(valid1,valid2,var,text):
    valid = [valid1,valid2]
    var = input(text)
    var = var.lower()
    if var not in valid:
        print ("Try again")
        valid_check(valid1,valid2,var,text)   // <--- Here
    else:
        print(var+" was accepted")
        return str(var)


Q2 = valid_check("a","b","Q2","a or b:")
print (Q2)
```

This is called a [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). When you call your method again, it works through it anew with the same values, then returns back into your original method invocation. However, the way you invoke it - by not assigning to a variable, causes the value that you `return` to go unused, so your original method invocation has nothing to return - it exits your `if else` block and exits without returning any value - hence the `None` you get.

Again suggest you to use a `while` loop as I have given in my example. I also advise you to read up a bit more on functions, loops and recursion, as the problems you seem to get are pretty basic.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the return function. This is great, i just thought a if loop and define loop would be more compact, but they are exactly the same. Thanks :)

Comment: Check the edit I've written. Please take a look into some books on Python or programming in general, you show some misunderstanding of the very basic programming concepts.